# Selenium in Python to download file: even after setting Firefox Profile the Download Window opens

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to use Selenium in Python to download a file from a website. In order to do that, I have read that I need to change the settings in my Firefox Profile to avoid opening the download dialogue window. I provided sample code below. This code works absolutely great at home, but it does not function properly with my work PC. I am suspecting that somehow Python can not change the settings of the firefox profile, even though the code below does not throw an error but rather works fine and in the end opens the download dialogue window.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\Ric\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\FirefoxProfileCopies\\ric.copy")

profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',('application/vnd.ms-excel'))

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)   
browser.get("http://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-xls.php")
elem1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".push-form > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)")
elem1.click()
```

This code works perfectly with my Firefox and its profile at home, but not with my computer at work. Does anybody know why this might be? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I tried to add all the `MIME`types from the Microsoft webpage, but still, the download manager window opens. When stopping the code to execute before opening the download link and trying to look at the settings for the used firefox profile with `about:config`the following values are displayed:
[image: Firefox Profile settings:]

Comment: Are you sure you search for downloaded file in correct folder? Try to replace `profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())` with `profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'C:\\Users\\Ric\\Desktop')`

Comment: Hello Anderson, thank you for your idea. I tried and the file does definitely not get download, it does not appear on my desktop. Firefox opens the download window and thus does not download yet. Any more ideas? I appreciate every hint.

Comment: Check whether file `MIME`-type is really `application/vnd.ms-excel`, you might need to add few more `MIME` types

Comment: I will try to do this, do you have suggestions which `MIME` types to add? Also, could this explain why it works at home but not with my PC at work?

Comment: Check this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/ for `MIME` types applicable to `MicrosoftOffice` files

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried to add all the `MIME` types that are related to Excel. Still the same output. This is weird, the must be some other parameter in the profile settings that needs to be changed. I edited my initial post to include some of the profile settings found by `about:config`after opening the browser from python with the webdriver and before trying to download the file. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Did you add `MIME` types as `profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12, ...")` ?

Comment: I have added the following: `profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',('application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template, application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12, application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12, application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12, application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12' ))` I do not know whether the "()" are important but I think they do not make a difference, do they? BTW thank you for staying on the issue

Comment: Try just a string without brackets

Comment: Same result without brackets. But I just tried the above code with an empty profile and it does download the file without the download manager window opening. I have to use a copy of my personal firefox profile though, due to access to certain internal pages. I will know try and compare the profile settings of the new empty profile and the copy of my personal firefox profile.

Comment: Andersson, thanks so much for your input. After comparing the settings of Firefox I figured out a solution by changing the settings for applications directly in Firefox. I added an answer. Thank you so much for your input and your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a lot of trying, I figured to look at the firefox settings in Firefox again, since it worked with an empty profile. I managed to resolve my issue and finally have the download window disappear by going to firefox, settings and changing the settings for applications:
[image: See the settings here]

Then, when opening this menu, search for excel and change the values from "asking every time" to "save file/download file". Sorry if these entries in the list differ from the actual ones in firefox but my Firefox is in German. After doing this, my issue was resolved. I hope it resolves somebody else :) and thanks to anderson.